# Merging two Datatables into One C#

Tags: c#, datatable, merge

I have a simple issue yet i can't resolve it , the issue is each time i merge two datatables the merge comes out to be funny looking , table 1 goes on top of table two , i know that is because i didn't set the primary key of the column ,but when i did suddenly i get error because having duplicate values in the Enitity column .How to get pass that , knowing that duplicate values will occur in the primary key column

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable merge = new DataTable() ;
                merge.Merge(t1());
                merge.Merge(t2());
                gridControl1.DataSource = merge.DefaultView;
            }
            public DataTable t1()
            {
                DataColumn col;

                DataTable d = new DataTable();
                d.Columns.Add("Enitity");

                d.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { d.Columns["Enitity"] };
                //d.PrimaryKey = null;
                d.Columns.Add("Variable");
                d.Rows.Add(new string []{"K1","100"});
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K1", "200" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K3", "300" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K4", "400" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K6", "500" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K5", "600" });
                return d;
            }
            public DataTable t2()
            {
                DataColumn col;
                DataTable d = new DataTable();
                d.Columns.Add("Enitity"); 
                d.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { d.Columns["Enitity"] };
                d.PrimaryKey = null;
                d.Columns.Add("Variable2");
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K1", "1000" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K2", "2000" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K3", "3000" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K4", "4000" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K5", "5000" });
                d.Rows.Add(new string[] { "K7", "6000" });
                return d;

            }
```

this is how my Merge looks Like

```
Enitty      Variable       Variable 2
---------     -----        -----------
K1              .
K2              .
K3              .
K4              .
.
.
.
K1                             .
K2                             .
K3                             .
K4
.
.
.
```

Comment: A PrimaryKey cannot have duplicate otherwise is no more a primary key

Comment: Thank for Reply , however i did know it must have no duplicate , but how can i come around this issue i want my Enitity Column to be merged ,

Comment: What do you expect to be your output? A table with three columns? Enitity, Variable and Variable2? If this is the case how do you plan to map the situation of K1? I mean the K1 row in table 2 has Variable2 set to 1000, which of the two rows with K1 in table1 should  be merged with the row in table2?

Comment: Yes sir , my out put should be exactly as you mentioned . The part of how i am going to do the merge is something beyond me , Thank for your comments

Comment: Are you sure that the second table could have a primary key on Enitity (I mean no duplicates are present there?)

Comment: @Steve thanks for your kind attention , however i have managed to merge the two tables as i was wishing , and the way i used is to create a new column (basically is 1,2,3,4) where are unique in each and every table . Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you don't want to merge *table*, you want to merge *rows*, and there isn't an automatic function for that (that I know of).

First of all, you will need to set the primary key --- without it, there's no way to know that "K1" from the first table wants to merge with "k1" from the second table.

Beyond that, as far as I know, you'll have to do the actual merge manually.  Copy Table1 to a new DataTable, add the extra column.  Then step through Table2, look up each key in the merge table, and add the new field.

UPDATE:   This should work for you:

```
DataTable merge = new DataTable() ;
merge.Merge(t1());
merge.Columns.Add("Variable2");
foreach(DataRow dr in t2().Rows)
{
    var old = merge.Select(string.Format("Enitity='{0}'", dr["Enitity"]) );
    if (old.Any())
        old[0]["Variable2"] = dr["Variable2"];
    else
          merge.Rows.Add(new string []{
                             dr["Enitity"] as string,
                             null, 
                             dr["Variable2"]as string});

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to do a [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx) then save the output of the join to a 3rd table. That is what the OP is really trying to do, the C# equivalent of the SQL `select t1.Enitty, t1.Variable, t2.Variable2 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.Enitty = t2.Enitty`.

Comment: What happen if there are more than one K3 in the second table? The result will omit this second row and update always the first K3 row in the first table

Comment: @Steve - Can't happen, as Entity is the *primary key* (no dups)

Answer (score 3):

As stated above, you cannot set the primary key because you have duplicate values. You're probably better off using linq, like:

```
        DataTable myNewDataTable = new DataTable();
        myNewDataTable.Columns.Add("Enitity", typeof(string));
        myNewDataTable.Columns.Add("Variable", typeof(string));
        myNewDataTable.Columns.Add("Variable2", typeof(string));
        var results = (from d1 in t1().AsEnumerable()
                       join d2 in t2().AsEnumerable()
                             on d1.Field<string>("Enitity") equals d2.Field<string>("Enitity")
                       select myNewDataTable.LoadDataRow( new object[] { d1.Field<string>("Enitity"), d1.Field<string>("Variable"), d2.Field<string>("Variable2") }, true) );
        myNewDataTable = results.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: A part from the fact that you cannot apply CopyToDataTable to results what happen to rows K2 and K7 in the second table? And the two K1 will have 1000 for both

Comment: I'm assuming that he actually wanted to join the table (using sql terms)... which is what I would expect since he tried to specify "Enititiy" as the primary key... I know it gets more complicated when you consider that there might be duplicates in both preexisting tables... but I didn't ask the question ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It depends on the behaviour that is desired, inner join, left outer join, right outer join, full outer join if this does exactly what he wants, but the example is for an inner join.